# how to change class of <a> tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table structure, something similar to

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="xx">one</a>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="xx">Two</a>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="xx">Three</a>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.xx {
    border: 5px solid green;    
}

.yy {
    border: 5px solid red;    
}
```

Now what I expect is, if I click on 1st row/1st `<a>` its border will turn to red, and rest of `<a>` in green, again if I clcik on 1st row/1st `<a>` it should turn to green. Also if I click on any other `<a>` then only it should turn to red, but rest of the `<a>` should be green.

I tried:

```
$(function () {
    $("a.xx").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("xx")) {
            $(this).removeClass("xx").addClass("yy");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("yy").addClass("xx");
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Check the error console. Do you get an error? Put some alert() or console.log() statements here and there. Does it print something?

Comment: no, its not giving error, lets say if I click on 1st <a> then its turning it to red, but then if I click on 2nd <a> it should turn to red, and 1st <a> should turn back to green, this functionality is not working.

Comment: just tested in firefox browser - I've got no errors and code is working fine.

Comment: You have open `<td>` elements. In some browsers it will hurt a lot. Ensure that your HTML is syntactically [valid](http://validator.w3.org) before fiddling with JS.

Comment: You might want to consider using .live('click', function(){ }); instead of .click, it is more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tweak the handler a bit, you can do so using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to swap classes, like this:

```
$("a.xx").click(function() {
  $(".yy").not(this).toggleClass("xx yy");
  $(this).toggleClass("xx yy");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ntqpu/3/), [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) takes multiple classes separated by a space, so to swap 2 classes just pass both.  In this case you want to on any that was toggle `.yy` and the current clicked element.

Or, since `.yy` is defined last in the CSS (and overrides the same properties) you can just *add* that class, like this:

```
$("a.xx").click(function() {
  $(".yy").not(this).removeClass("yy");
  $(this).toggleClass("yy");
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ntqpu/4/).

Comment: Partially working-
Not working part: if I click on <a> it should turn to red, if I again click the same <a> it should turn to green.this part is not working, rest are fine.

Comment: @Wondering - Ah, you can do that by changing `$(".yy")` to `$(".yy").not(this)`, one second and I'll update the answer and demo.

Comment: @Wondering - Updated, give it a try now :)

Comment: @Nick- Your points, number of accepted ans and upvote is also updated.Take a look  :-)

Comment: BTW , can u pls explain a bit, i mean How should I have proceed to olve the problem

Comment: @Wondering - I'm not sure which problem you're trying to solve, do you have another question open? Or is there something in this one I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are attaching a handler only to the a.xx click event.  You also need one for the a.yy click event.  What I would recommend is adding another class for these highlights then going from there, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="xx highlight"></a>

$('a.highlight').click(function({
  $('a.xx,a.yy').toggleClass('xx yy');
});
```

Comment: False. When the page loads all `<a>` elements have class xx, so the event is bound to all `<a>` elements.

Comment: Not my downvote, but this would toggle all of the rows, rather than making only the current `.yy`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says nothing about turning other things green. You need to do two things upon a click: turn everything green, then turn the current one red. You are doing the second part, but not the first one.

Answer (score -1):

You only change the class of $(this), so none of the other links will change color.

Try this:

```
        $("a.xx").click(function () {
            $('a.yy').removeClass('yy').addClass('xx');
            $(this).removeClass('xx').addClass('yy');
        });
```

Comment: Partially working- Not working part: if I click on <a> it should turn to red, if I again click the same <a> it should turn to green.this part is not working, rest are fine