# what exactly this code is doing

Tags: jquery

Based on this answer - [how to change classes on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778647/how-to-change-classes-on-click)
can somebody explain me what exactly the code below is doing?

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this); // this is just for performance
  if(!$this.hasClass('yy'))
    $('.yy').toggleClass("yy").toggleClass("xx");
  $this.toggleClass("yy").toggleClass("xx");
});
```

I mean the last two lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, it finds all of the `a` elements (links).

It sets their on-click actions to a function which:

1. checks to see if that link currently has the `yy` CSS class.
2. If it doesn't, then it turns off the `yy` class on everything which has it and toggles the `xx` on those that used to have the `yy` class.
3. After that, it toggles the `yy` and `xx` classes on the link that was clicked.

Comment: One further way to clarify the code is to write `$('.yy').removeClass("yy").toggleClass("xx");` instead of `$('.yy').toggleClass("yy").toggleClass("xx");`.